# how to insert a new row into an html table by jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have following html table layout:

```
<table border="1" id="staff">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12">
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="13">
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="15">
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="16">
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I insert new row by the following jquery code after getting a retrieved row id. The new row will be inserted after that row which has a id less than the retrieved id. I can do this in two way. 1st one is as below:

**method:1:**

```
var retrieved_id = 11; 
var newRow = '<tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr>';

var previous_id = $('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return this.id < rank;
}).last().attr('id');

var previous_row = $("#" + previous_id).closest("tr");
previous_row.after(newRow);
```

The code works well until the `retrieved_id` is >=2 (greater than or equal to). But if the `retrieved_id` is 1, then the less id of 1 become 'undefined' as there is no id less than 1. In that case, I can't insert a in row in such position. I can resolve this by directly entering the row without identifying `previous_id` by this way:

**method:2**

```
var rank = 1; // calculate this as needed...
var newRow = '<tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr>';

$('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return this.id < rank;
}).last().after(newRow);
```

But for later part of my page, I also need to know the `previous_id` as well. So I can't use **method:2**, instead I have to use **method:1**.

Can anyone tell me, how can I resolve the `retrieved_id = 1` issue using the **method:1**?

Comment: Is this what you wanted ? https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/rdyq5p5x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the `retrieved_id` equals to `1` and if so, do not filter the table for the previous id and just insert it at the top of the table.

```js
var retrieved_id = 1;
var newRow = '<tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr>';
if (retrieved_id == 1) {
  if ($('table >tbody').length == 0) {
    newRow = '<tbody><tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr></tbody>';
    $(newRow).prependTo('table');
  } else if ($('table >tbody >tr').length == 0) {
    $(newRow).prependTo('table > tbody');
  } else {
    $(newRow).insertBefore('table > tbody > tr:first');
  }
} else {
  var previous_id = $('#staff tr').filter(function() {
    return this.id < retrieved_id;
  }).last().attr('id');
}
var previous_row = $("#" + previous_id).closest("tr");
previous_row.after(newRow);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="staff">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
      <td>Christina Berglund</td>
      <td>Sweden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="5">
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="8">
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="9">
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="12">
      <td>Königlich Essen</td>
      <td>Philip Cramer</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="13">
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="15">
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="16">
      <td>North/South</td>
      <td>Simon Crowther</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> EDIT

Or else, after calculating the `previous_id` check whether it is `undefined`, and if that is the case, (which means there are no `tr`s having `id`s less than the `retrieved_id`) just add the new row to the top of the table,

```
var retrieved_id = 1;
var newRow = '<tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr>';

var previous_id = $('#staff tr').filter(function () {
    return this.id < retrieved_id;
}).last().attr('id');
if (typeof previous_id == 'undefined') {
    $(newRow).insertBefore('table > tbody > tr:first');
}
var previous_row = $("#" + previous_id).closest("tr");
previous_row.after(newRow);
```

Comment: Nice try, but what if there is no tr after thead, i,e there is no row except table header(thead)? then how your code will insert before first row? isn't it better to insert it after thead or tbody tag? if so, plz mention the code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I have edited my answer to handle both the two cases where there is no `tbody` tag. And where there is `tbody` tag but `tr`s are missing. Hope this is what you expect..

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `$.inArray()` , `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var retrieved_id = 8;

var newRow = "<tr><td>The new row HTML...</td></tr>";

var elems = $("#staff tbody tr").get();

elems.splice($.inArray($("#" + retrieved_id)[0], elems) + 1, 0, newRow);

$("#staff tbody").html(elems);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="staff">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr id="1">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="5">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="8">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="9">
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12">
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="13">
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
 <tr id="15">
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="16">
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```